# Haskell - install error with stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

If I try to run `stack install lens` I get

```
lens-4.15.1: configure

--  While building package lens-4.15.1 using:
      /home/marcosh/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/ghc --make -odir /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.0.2/setup -hidir /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.0.2/setup -i -i. -package=Cabal-2.0.0.2 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=/home/marcosh/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/Setup.lhs /home/marcosh/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs -main-is StackSetupShim.mainOverride -o /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.0.2/setup/setup -threaded
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/marcosh/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/lens-4.15.1.log

    [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/Setup.lhs, /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.0.0.2/setup/Main.o )

    /tmp/stack11968/lens-4.15.1/Setup.lhs:7:31: error:
        Module
        ‘Distribution.Package’
        does not export
        ‘PackageName(PackageName)’
```

I am using the following version of `stack`

```
Version 1.5.1, Git revision 600c1f01435a10d127938709556c1682ecfd694e (4861 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.17.1
```

and version `8.0.2` of `GHC`.

I also did a `stack update`.

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve the issue?

--- EDIT ---

My global `stack.yaml` file looks like

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages: []
extra-deps: []
resolver: lts-8.23
```

I tried to update the resolver to `lts-9.4` but I still get (other) errors

--- EDIT 2 ---

The output of `stack exec ghc-pkg list Cabal` is

```
/home/marcosh/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d
    Cabal-1.24.2.0
    Cabal-2.0.0.2
/home/marcosh/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
    (no packages)
/home/marcosh/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-8.23/8.0.2/pkgdb
    (no packages)
```

Comment: What does your stack.yaml file look like? Have you pulled in a new version of Cabal by any chance?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman I updated the question with my `stack.yaml`. I did not updated Cabal, I still have the 1.24.0.2 version which came down with ghc

Comment: Can you also include the output of `stack exec ghc-pkg list Cabal`? And what happens if, outside your project, you run `stack build --resolver lts-8.23 lens`?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman edited again the question with the output of the command you suggested. If I run `stack build --resolver lts-8.23 lens` on a newly created empty folder, I get the same error

Comment: It looks like you've somehow installed Cabal-2.0.0.2 globally. Since lens-4.15.1 does not use a custom-setup stanza in its cabal file, Stack doesn't know that it is incompatible with Cabal 2. I think your easiest path forward would be to add lens-4.15.4 to your extra-deps.

Comment: I removed by hand Cabal-2.0.0.2 from `~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/lib/ghc-8.0.2/package.conf.d` and  everything seems to be working fine